# How to load only chosen frames from TIFF image stack into memory, without having to load everything

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, lazy-loading, scikit-image

I am working with large TIFF image stacks that are equivalent to NumPy arrays on the order of `(300, 2048, 2048)`. I am interested in writing a function that allows me to quickly pick `n` chosen slices from the array for plotting and comparison, to see how the image has evolved. However, most of the methods I am aware of involve having to load the entire thing to memory first, which my desktop cannot handle.

Could you advise on how I could optimise my code in order to quickly identify slices of the array within the image stack to load and plot, *without having to load the whole stack to memory first*?

**Working Attempt:**
The advice provided by @Malcolm below worked perfectly, allowing me to load the image stack metadata and individual slices without having to load the whole stack into memory. The `key=` argument in `io.imread()` allows for individual slices of the image stack to be loaded, and the `TiffFile()` class(?) allows for the file metadata to be loaded without loading the actual array.

```
# Import relevant modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tifffile import TiffFile
from skimage import io


# Load file
file = "example.tiff"  # Array of dimensions (300, 2048, 2048)
stk = TiffFile(file)  # Load file metadata

# Check number of figures to plot in subplot
frm_sep = 10  # Frames between images
num_frm = 6

# Create figure and subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num_frm, sharey=True)
for i in range(num_frm):
    # Load image reference image to adjust intensities
    if i == 0:
        img_ref = io.imread(fft, key=0)
        v_max=np.percentile(np.ravel(img_ref), 99)
    else: pass
    
    # Plot subplot
    ax = axs[i]
    ax.imshow(
        io.imread(fft, key=(i * frm_sep)),
        vmin=0,
        vmax=v_max
    )
    ax.set_title(f"Frame {i * frm_sep}")
```

**My Original Attempt:**

```
# Import relevant modules
from skimage import io
import dask.array as da
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load file
file = "example.tiff"  # Array dimensions of (300,2048, 2048)
img_stk = da.from_array(io.imread(file), chunks=(1, 512, 512)  # Tried using dask array for lazy loading

# Load image stack to array
frm_sep = 10  # Frames separating images
num_frm = 6  # Number of frames to show

# Create figure to plot these chosen frames
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num_frm, sharey=True)
for i in range(num_frm):
    # Display on subplot
    axs[i].imshow(img_stk[i * frm_sep],
                  vmin=0,
                  vmax=np.percentile(np.ravel(img_stk[0]), 99)
                  )
    # Set subplot title
    axs[i].set_title(f"Frame {i * frm_sep}")
```

The code works, but the loading of the image stack takes a few minutes each time, which to me indicates that I am loading the whole stack instead of my chosen slices.

Comment: The `io.imread(file)` call is definitely going to read the entire file.  From the skimage docs (https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.io.html) it looks like it uses the tiffile package to load TIFF images.  And from the tiffile package documentation (https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/#examples), it looks like that package supports what you want with its `key=...` option .  Since the skimage.io docs indicate that imread takes `**plugin_args`, I would try using `io.imread(file, key=...)`.

Comment: Note it still may take time to read through the file to find the requested images.  Checking your process's memory usage would probably be a better measure of whether the entire image stack is being loaded into memory.

Comment: The other option is to use tifffile directly.  From a couple of examples lower on the examples page I referenced earlier, it shows that the `tifffile.TiffFile` class allows you to read TIFF files in a "page" at a time.

Comment: Hi @Malcolm, apologies for the delay in responding, and thank you for your helpful suggestions! I can confirm that `io.imread(file, key=...)` works perfectly for the purposes of this script. I have also had a look a the `tifffile.TiffFile` command you suggested, and can confirm that it allows me to read the file metadata without loading the file into memory. I've edited my original block of code with the optimised version. Many thanks!